# Who is the king of social media?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

- My prefix is the sound of shots.
- My infix is when one gets shot
- My suffix is a round thing.
- My whole is a media king.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Surely you must mean

> PewDiePie, [the moneymakingest guy on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie).

Given that each "fix" is already capitalised, that's probably enough of an explanation.

Comment: That's really good. I never would've thought of that.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are looking for:

> **PewDiePie**

My prefix is the sound of shots.

> Kids make **pew** sounds, when playing with imaginary or toy guns [UrbanDictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pew%20gun).

My infix is when one gets shot

> Someone can **die** from a gunshot

My suffix is a round thing

> **Pie**s are usually round.

My whole is a media king

> **PewDiePie** is a famous youtuber [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie)

Who is the king of social media?

> According to [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.de/international/most-popular-youtubers-with-most-subscribers-2018-2/?r=US&IR=T) PewDiePie is the youtuber with the most subscribers.

Comment: i thought rot13(cvr e fdhner).  my mistake.

Comment: Isn't this the same as Bass's answer?

Comment: I wanted to add a complete answer, as his unedited answer was just a link to youtube, which honestly I didn't click on.

Comment: It's worth noting that rot13(CrjQvrCvr vf bssvpvnyyl gur [xvat bs LbhGhor](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=TVm4X97OMYWs5NoPtL-0-AQ&q=who+is+the+king+of+youtube&oq=who+is+the+king&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgBMggIABDJAxCRAjIFCAAQkQIyAgguMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoNCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoHCAAQyQMQQzoECAAQQzoHCAAQsQMQQ1DNDFj_IGCGLGgAcAB4AIABiwGIAawNkgEEMy4xM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab)).

Comment: @Torben Also, I agree that adding an explanation is key.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this should be the accepted answer. It was the first to explain each line, which is standard fare with these types of riddles (and maybe riddles in general).

Comment: @oAlt Yes, but the thing is, this answer might not have existed if the other answer didn't exist. I'm sorry if I'm wrong, Torben. Am I?

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for:

> **Snapchat**

> My prefix is the sound of shots.

> A sonic boom caused by a gunshot can produce a "**snap**" sound - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunshot).

> My infix is when one gets shot

> When someone gets shot, they often lose consciousness. So, you could say they "took a **nap**".

> My suffix is a round thing

> Well, that would be a **hat**.

> My whole is a media king

> Snapchat is a popular social media app/platform. <sub><sup>*(although I never used it myself)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: But then where does the rot13(p) come from? As is, you only give 7/8 letters of your suggested answer.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp I think you're right. I'm not really familiar with the rules of affix riddles. I've seen similar puzzles before where the prefix, infix, and suffix overlap. So, I guess I was under the impression that they also don't have to cover all the letters.

Comment: Hi, Snapchat is not a person, it is a social media app. The question is: **Who** is the king of social media, not What is the king of social media.