# The king of the social media? (Again?)

Tags: riddle, word

The beginning of my name began with a **single** letter.

I post music songs.

> (not English)

I am popular for my songs

Who am I?

Comment: This seems far more like trivia than a proper riddle - all the clues are extremely straightforward.

Comment: @bobble I do agree with you. This is why I was able to get the answer almost immediately after reading the question. I think he got the inspiration from [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105036/who-is-the-king-of-social-media), which is a much more well-written one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is just trivia, with very straightforward clues.

Comment: Please do not change your riddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I instantly knew who you are, you are:

> T-Series

The beginning of my name began with a single letter and an “-“.

> Your name is T-Series, which begins with a single letter and an "-".

I post music songs(not English)

> T-Series posts music songs that are not in English

I am hated by PewDiePie

> PewDiePie hates T-Series, he even made a diss track on it.

Comment: Yessss, good job!

Comment: @Jingbothedude Just do take note that T-Series is a company and not a person.